# Redux see other state from Reducer

Tags: javascript, redux

Imagine a UI with two React components:

`<FilterContainer />`

`<UserListContainer />`

We pull down an array of users from the server:

```
[
  {
    name: 'John',
    enjoys: ['Sailing', 'Running']
  },
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    enjoys: ['Running', 'Eating']
  },
  {
    name: 'Frank',
    enjoys: ['Sailing', 'Eating']
  }
]
```

The UI looks a little like this:

Filter: **Sailing** Running Eating

UserList:

John

**Frank**

You can click on either a filter or a user. To get to this stage, we've clicked on 'Sailing' and then on 'Frank' (maybe we see a nice photo of Frank in the middle of the screen).

My Redux state, built using `combineReducers`, looks like this:

```
{
  ui: { 
    filter: {enjoys: 'Sailing'},
    userList: {selected: 'John'}
  }
  data: [user array]
}
```

I have two actions, `SELECT_USER` and `SELECT_FILTER`.

When I click on a filter (`SELECT_FILTER` fires), I want the `ui.userList.selected` to persist if that user is still in the filter, and the `ui.userList.selected` to be set to null if the user is not in the filter.

So if I now click on Eating, I'll see a list with Bob and **Frank** in it, and Frank is selected. But if I click on Running, I'll see John and Bob, but neither are selected.

However I'm struggling to do this in the conventional Redux methodology. When the `userList` reducer sees the `SELECT_FILTER` action, there's no way for it to check the `data` state to see if the currently selected user is still in that filter condition or not.

What's the right way to do this?

```
function filter(state = {enjoys: null}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_FILTER:
      return {
        ...state,
        enjoys: action.enjoys
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function userList(state = {selected: null}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        selected: action.name
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const ui = combineReducers({
  filter,
  userList
})

let initialUsers = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    enjoys: ['Sailing', 'Running']
  },
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    enjoys: ['Running', 'Eating']
  },
  {
    name: 'Frank',
    enjoys: ['Sailing', 'Eating']
  }
]

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  ui,
  data: (state=initialUsers) => state // in reality, loaded from server
})

export default rootReducer
```

Answer (score 2):

Reducer should be aware only of a small part of state.

Good place for described logic is the action creator. With redux-thunk you will be able to make a decision based on a global state.

```
function selectFilter(enjoys) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({type: SELECT_FILTER, enjoys});
    // if getState().ui.userList.selected exists in getState().data
    dispatch({type: SELECT_USER, name: null});
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need another action for this.

If you are filtering the users in the data reducer, you will need to dispatch an action in one of your components' hooks (componentWillUpdate or componentWillReceiveProps) when you detect that the array of users has changed. This action will provide your filter reducer with the current array of users, and there you can set the selected field as you like.

If you are filtering the users in the server, I guess you already have an action like FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS that you can use for this.

Comment: My container for the user list only passes the filtered user list to the User List Component, which I understood we should be keeping as 'dumb' or simple as possible. Having a component fire an action whenever it receives new props doesn't seem like a clean separation of concerns to me? This should be calculated in the state any time a filter is clicked on, not when the user list receives new props?

Comment: Also I'm not sure about the data flow here? We send our SELECT_FILTER event, the new filtered user list gets passed to the User List Component by the container, and then there may be a mismatch between the selected user in the state and what is being displayed on screen, as the component will render before the componentWillUpdate hook sends the 'FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS' action and selected user gets updated?

Essentially I can see how this works, but is it really better than having a reducer that can look in the entire state tree and calculate Selected User whenever a SELECT_FILTER action fires?

Answer (score 0):

It should be handled by the filter reducer. You need to send the users data as part of the action payload. Hence the reducer could Calc the selected user logic. You should consider adding a new action, as @cuttals suggested.

Comment: What if there are multiple different filter components/reducers, each with separate state? E.g. an 'Enjoys filter' and an 'Age filter'. Then which of these two reducers should own this task? I don't think it make sense to keep the 'selected user' state inside the state owned by one of potentially many different filter components? Especially if we want to re-use components, some pages may have an 'Enjoys filter' and some an 'Age filter', and some both.